# How to align a Nvme SSD partiotion after installation?

Tags: partitioning, ssd, 16.04, nvme

I've install Ubuntu 16.04 in a Nvme SSD,but I found the partion 6 isn't  aligned automatically  through parted command:

```
sudo parted /dev/nvme0n1
(parted) align-check optimal 6 
6 not aligned
```

This is the output of fdisk:

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: C49EAE3F-0A58-468E-99E5-2B51CB2A2FBC

设备               Start    末尾    扇区   Size 类型
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048   1026047   1024000   500M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2   1026048   1288191    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3   1288192 217038149 215749958 102.9G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 477204480 478126079    921600   450M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p5 478126080 500117503  21991424  10.5G Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p6 217038150 477204479 260166330 124.1G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

So how could I realign the partition?(expecting not reinstall os )

Comment: @DavidFoerster I've append fdisk's output,please help me~

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thx~